# How to change the set of points on the map, if the new set of points contains some of the points of the first set?

Tags: here-api

How to change the set of points(markers and clusters) on the map, if the new set of points contains some of the points of the first set (for example, this search result)?

If you use "removeLayer", we see the old points (clusters) are removed and after a while the new points are drawn.

Is it possible to add only missing (difference) points to the map without removing the old points, if they are in the new set of points, and delete the old points if they are not in the new set of points?

Answer (score 1):

Any action like adding or removing of a dataPoint will force a re-clustering.

Even when you would implement a method which only performs an update(which is possible) the effect would be the same as if you create a new layer